# Compatibilidad con IE5 y superior: replaceState, para cambiar parámetro

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Estoy tratando de modificar un parámetro que se envía por la url al controlador (quiero modificar el valor del parámetro `action` y darle un valor `action=P`).

Estoy intentando aplicar la siguiente función JS, que funciona correctamente en los navegadores modernos y que he sacado de otro post.

Sin embargo, necesito que también sea compatible con Internet Explorer 5, el cual me lanza el siguiente error:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'replaceState'

Estuve tratando de utilizar History.js pero no fui capaz de solucionarlo.

PEGO LA FUNCIÓN:

```
    /* http://stackoverflow.com/a/10997390/11236 */

function updateURLParameter(url, param, paramVal){
    var newAdditionalURL = "";
    var tempArray = url.split("?");
    var baseURL = tempArray[0];
    var additionalURL = tempArray[1];
    var temp = "";
    if (additionalURL) {
        tempArray = additionalURL.split("&");
        for (var i=0; i<tempArray.length; i++){
            if(tempArray[i].split('=')[0] != param){
                newAdditionalURL += temp + tempArray[i];
                temp = "&";
            }
        }
    }

    var rows_txt = temp + "" + param + "=" + paramVal;
    return baseURL + "?" + newAdditionalURL + rows_txt;
}
```

LLAMADA A LA FUNCIÓN

```
window.history.replaceState('', '', updateURLParameter(window.location.href, "action", "P"));
```

Comment: ¿Es absolutamente necesario que funcione en IE5? Cuando el propio Microsoft ha recomendado no usar IE11, seguir manteniendo IE5 me parece increíble.

Comment: Lo sé pero no es decisión mía, debe funcionar necesariamente en IE5 también

Comment: ¿Estamos hablando de Windows 98 SE?

Comment: Desconozco el sistema operativo pero creo que es moderno. Lo que sí deber ser compatible con IE5

Comment: Tampoco quiero dar mucho la "vara" con eso pero creo que es más fácil eliminar IE5 de la ecuación que hacer cambios en vuestros javascript para adecuarlos a ES2 (más si cabe si están utilizando un sistema operativo moderno)

Comment: como ya dije no es cosa mía, tiene que poder utilizarse en IE5  además de en las versiones más modernas del IE

Comment: La leche, IE5... yo pediría un aumento de sueldo o un plus de peligrosidad.